# Как подключить .vue файл как скрипт в rails assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Проблема в том, что нужно подключить `.vue` файлы как скрипты через `application.js`. Тоесть нужно чтобы при добавлении строки `require_tree ./components/` в `application.js` подключались `.vue` файлы как js скрипты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Новое Rails 5 приложение:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=vue
```

Или можно поставить на уже готовое Rails приложение:

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 2.0'
```

Далее:

```
rails webpacker:install
rails webpacker:install:vue
```

Больше информации: https://github.com/rails/webpacker

При этом вам необходимо установить [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) на машину.

Для запуска проекта в development среде используйте:

```
gem 'foreman'
```

И в корне проекта разместите файл Procfile с этим содержимым:

```
backend: bin/rails s -p 3000
frontend: bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Запуск проекта как development осуществляется этой командой:

```
foreman start
```

Запуск проекта в production среде осуществялется как обычно.